# NoReverseMatch at /update/

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm using the author name for posts in the url. I get this error after clicking on the submit button when updating the post or creating a new post:

```
Reverse for 'post-detail' with keyword arguments '{'id': 2, 'author': 'john'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<author>[^/]+)\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank="true")
    content =models.TextField(default="Enter details", verbose_name="Content")
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title 



    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'id' :  self.pk, 'author': self.author.username})
```

Views.py

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post 
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user ##author = current logged in user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True 
        return False
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    
    path('<str:author>/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('<str:author>/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('<str:author>/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
   

]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**'post_detail'** URL accepts two keyword argument by the names **'pk'**, and **'author'**, so you need to change **get_absolute_url** to

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk, 'author': self.author})
```

Comment: not working, getting this error: Reverse for 'post-detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<author>[^/]+)\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']

Comment: sorry my bad, please recheck my answer

Comment: you need to share the PostDetailView, as author argument needs to be a string, you might need to change from self.auhor to self.author.username or self.author.email